# Write a ff file

Tags: r, matrix, large-files, ffbase

I am working with large matrix on R and I try to use the ff package to manipulate them.

I have a loop which will create n (n can be size 1000) matrix called Var_sim (dim 25*7303)
I want to save the matrix in the disk (for example in my documents) with the ff format. After that if I need to read one of the n matrix I want to load it with R and ffload. This is my code:

```
    ffmat <- as.ff(Var_sim)
    ffsave(ffmat, file="/home/username/Documents/Data")
```

But nothing appears in Data: I don't know if ffsave is the function I am looking for.
Moreover I don't know how to specify the name of the file which will be create.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the file name you want to save it as instead of just giving the directory name, e.g.

```
ffsave(ffmat, file="/home/username/Documents/Data/ffmat1")
```